# Programmatically running commands on remote Linux server using R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio-server

I was able to use the `shell()`command on R to write out the instructions to gaining access to the AWS EC2 Linux server.

```
shell("chmod 400 rstudio.pem")

shell("ssh -i \"rstudio.pem\" ec2-user@[address number here].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com")
```

But once I gained access to the Linux server from R. And I tried running

```
shell("sudo yum -y update")
```

It would not run and just stayed in thinking mode for a while and then I recieved an error saying "The Child Process is not running. Click ok to terminate it".

How do I run commands on the Linux server once I gain access from R running on my computer?

Comment: Is this question looking to script an interactive ssh session? or open an ssh connection and run a static series of commands on the remote server?

Comment: @jessica, @GcL did you have any success in running the shell commands on a remote server via R? I'm trying to submit a `slurm job` after successful ssh to the remote server. The jobs are submitted , `squeue` shows as waiting, as soon as it changes to Run, it fails ( don't see any error on the console or on remote server).

Comment: @user5249203 It can e done, but it's not a good idea.  If you've already got ssh access, just ssh into the controller node.  Your problem sounds like one with your the jobs you're trying to run and is not relevant to this question.

Comment: I come from a biology background, may I know why it is not a good idea? You are right, it's not directly related to the question, my issue was similar in terms of being unable to execute commands from R GUI to a remote server

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is that each call to `shell` is being executed in its own process.  So the ssh command that is opened in the first process isn't what is receiving the commands being issued in the subsequent shell calls.

Assuming the underlying shell is bash, you can demonstrate this using:

```
# echo PID of shell
system('echo $$') # 20859
system('echo $$') # 20860
```

If you're intent on using R as your entry point into invoking ssh, you can pass commands to execute remotely as part of your call to ssh.  This uses ssh to connect and run the command all in a single call.

E.g. get disk usage from remote host

```
command <- 'ssh -i "rstudio.pem" ec2-user@[address number here].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com df -H'
system(command)
```

I expect your command will look like the following:

```
command <- 'ssh -i "rstudio.pem" ec2-user@[address number here].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com sudo yum -y update'
system(command)
```

If you wanted to run a series of commands, you could try listed them as the inputs.  This will in turn pass them to ssh via stdin.  That has a little bit of a peculiar behavior, but might suffice for your purposes.

```
inputs <- c('echo "Starting Command"', 'df -h', 'echo "All done."')
command <- 'ssh -i "rstudio.pem" ec2-user@your.aws.ec2.address'
system(command, input=inputs)
```

Comment: I was able to get into the Server. This is not the issue. I actually did the commands you mentioned, I simply forgot to include that in my post. Once i gained successful access to the Linux server on R. R went into thinking mode and no aaditional commands could be inputed.

Comment: @jessica what was the result of the command string that ends with `df -h` ? Does that also hang, or does that return the output of the disk space usage on the remote host?

Comment: After I run the commands that you mentioned, system(command). It successfully accesses the server and it hangs. If I run df -h, it also hangs. But once I termiante the session and I run it remotely, it works.

Comment: @jessica interesting.  So you can run the ssh commands locally from the command line and they work, but invoking them via R's `system()` call hangs?

Comment: I first run: `>command <- 'ssh -i "rstudio.pem" ec2-user@[address number here].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com'
>system(command)` then it hangs then I run `>command='df -h' >system(command)`and it still continues to hang with no response.

Comment: @jessica I see.  They're not two separate commands.  The `df -h` is part of the ssh call.  That tells ssh to connect and then execute `df -h` and print the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194263/discussion-between-gcl-and-jessica).